# Using a local variable "delivered" that is not assigned a value

Tags: c#

I have set the DateTime delivered variable and I need to get the modified variable from the "GetQuantityInStock" stored procedure in order to apply it in the next request. How can I do that?

Error: Using a local variable "delivered" that is not assigned a value.

```
private void InsertQuery()
{
    var count =
            from order in showOrders
            group order by order.ProductArticleNumber into articles
            select new
            {
                ProductArticleNumber = articles.Key,
                Count = articles.Count(),
            };

    DateTime today = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
    DateTime delivered;
    int id;

    if (cboPickUpPoints.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        int pickUpPoint = (int)cboPickUpPoints.SelectedValue;


        if (MessageBox.Show("Вы точно уверены в своём выборе? ", "Сообщение",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString))
            {
                connectionString.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "GetCountArticles";
                cmd.Connection = connectionString;

                foreach (var items in count)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countArticles", items.Count);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductArticleNumber", items.ProductArticleNumber);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd1.CommandText = "GetQuantityInStock";
                cmd1.Connection = connectionString;

                foreach (var items in count)
                {
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductArticleNumber", items.ProductArticleNumber);
                    int countArticles = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (countArticles > 3)
                    {
                        delivered = today.AddDays(3); //<-- The variable I need
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        delivered = today.AddDays(6); //<-- The variable I need
                    }
                }

                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd2.CommandText = "InsertOrder";
                cmd2.Connection = connectionString;

                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", today);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDeliveryDate", delivered); //<-- Error
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderPickupPoint", pickUpPoint);
```

Comment: The issue is that the surrounding foreach-loop does not garanty a value will be assigned to 'delivered' - resulting in the the error you see

Comment: Probably you meant to use DateTime? instead.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `count` is empty?

Comment: @JonSkeet In the calculation I take the number of Articles that I select in the previous form.

Comment: @xflx: But what value of `delivery` would you expect to use, given that it wouldn't be assigned anywhere if `count` is empty? (It's unhelpful that the variable `count` really sounds like it'll be a number, when it's actually a collection...)

Comment: Additionally, do you *really* want the value of `delivery` to only depend on the last item in `count`? That seems pretty arbitrary to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing `delivered` inside of a `foreach` statement body which is not guaranteed to be executed (if `count` is empty) at least from the compiler point of view.

just initialize it something:

```
DateTime delivered = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

or rewrite code in the way that it is initialized and used in correct place.

Also it seems a bit strange that you are calculating a single date per batch, basically it will result in the `countArticles` analyzed only for the last item in `count` which can produce inconsistent results depending on the order of the items in `count`. If you are adamant on using stored procedures then I would recommend to rewrite both `GetCountArticles` and `ProductArticleNumber` to accept collection of ids (for example like using [table valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) for SQL server) and process them in batch on the db side (i.e. `ProductArticleNumber` will become `MaxProductArticleNumber` or similar)

Also note that there are arguments against using `AddWithValue` - see [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Depending on the number of articles that I select in the previous form, the delivery time depends, that is, if the number of articles is less than 3, then the delivery time will be 6 days, if more than 3, then 3 days. Therefore, I don’t know how to correctly write logic for this.

Comment: @xflx your result depends on the order you have in the `count` which can fluctuate. I.e. you will get different result for the same items if one time they are returned in order with `countArticles` > 3 first and next time with `countArticles ` <= 3 first.

Comment: @xflx Write `MaxProductArticleNumber` function which will accept table value parameter with `ProductArticleNumber` column (and pass all `ProductArticleNumber`s at a time) and returns the maximum number of article in the batch.